Losing Gatsby Link state when opening page in a new tab
I created a Link with state prop in Gatsby App.
<Link 
to={`/blog`} 
state={{ data: {data}}}
>
MyLink
</Link>


In my blog site I refer to the data value:
const [data, setData]  = useState(props.location.state?.data.data);

After opening this link on a new tab, I loose the data prop value in my blog site-> data value is null
If I click on that Link in the same tab, it works fine.
How can I implement a solution to work in both cases?
Using window.history.state instead of state prop in my blog site didn't work for me, too.
var data = []
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
   data  = window.history.state?.data;
}

